# How to improve the website SEO by "Find and Replace Text" in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress, replace

I know that if we need to change any text in MySQL, then we will use this format:

```
update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME =
replace(FIELD_NAME, 'Text to find', 'text to replace with');
```

For example, if you wanted to search for text in a WordPress post’s content, then you would write your query like this:

```
update wp_posts set post_content =
replace(post_content,'DDDDDD','DDDDDY');
```

I am looking for a method to replace some words inside posts contents with hyperlinks, this will incredibly enhance the internal linking of the website and enhance the SEO. The point is that we need this to be limited to the first two paragraphs ( for example; the first 300 letters), and to limit this replacement to 3 changes per post. 
If we can review the change before its made, that will be a great option.

I am not a coder so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a programming task, not an SQL task.

Answer (score 0):

What did you try or archive?

WordPress have many plugins that auto add internal links and have options to limit number of links in current post. Take a look at: [Seo Auto Links](https://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-auto-links/)

So you just need to write you focus keyword in first 300 letters, and that plugin automatically add internal links for you.